# O que é dívida técnica?

Tags: terminologia, gerenciamento-de-projetos

A dívida técnica é a soma de alguns tipos de pendências no seu projeto que podem impedir a evolução do mesmo. Entretanto, esse conceito é muito mais abrangente do que isso, e eu gostaria de ter as seguintes dúvidas respondidas para ajudar a entender melhor o conceito.

Ao que exatamente se refere essa dívida? Por que ela impede a evolução do desenvolvimento do projeto? Existe uma taxa aceitável dessa dívida dentro do projeto?

Comment: Divida técnica não é algo super bem definido e mensurável. É simplesmente o nome que damos pra todas aquelas gambiarras que fazemos mesmo sabendo que vão morder nosso bumbum mais tarde.

Comment: Aqui é permitido aquelas risadas esdrúxulas do tipo  haeuaheuhaeuhaeuhae? Porque eu ri desse comentário. :D

Comment: AHAHAHAHAHAAHAHAA

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Podemos recorrer ao [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) para ter uma definição aceitável.

A grosso modo são todas as atividades inerentes ao desenvolvimento, mas não diretamente funcionalidades definidas no projeto, que o desenvolvedor ou equipe de desenvolvimento vai deixando pra trás inconscientemente ou conscientemente sem controle, à revelia do planejamento da equipe. É algo que todos sabem que existe, mas é difícil identificar onde ela está. Na prática estamos sempre em dívida técnica quando começamos a executar um projeto. Você pode minimizar seus efeitos, mas não pode combatê-la por completo. Sempre existem atividades que beneficiariam o projeto e que são esquecidas ou relegadas em função de restrições sempre existentes.

Alguns dizem que uma metodologia ágil ajuda combater a existência destas dívidas, outros afirmam que na verdade ela é responsável pelo aumento destas dívidas. A minha experiência é que *agile* costuma ajudar identificar estas dívidas, o que é bom, mas também ajuda a criá-las. Em nome da metodologia, o resultado acaba sendo prejudicado.

Há quem diga que a tentativa de evitar estas dívidas causam atrasos nos projetos. Outros dizem que deixar as dívidas causam atrasos maiores ao longo do tempo porque acarretam trabalho extra que não seria necessário de outra forma.

Uma coisa é certa, por mais que uma metodologia qualquer possa ajudar se não houver vontade e recursos a dívida vai sempre aumentar. E se considerarmos a dívida como inevitável não podemos considerá-las como algo inerentemente danoso. Projetos de software são complicados e a busca pela perfeição pode até ajudar identificar dívidas técnicas, mas pode gerar novas. Achar o equilíbrio entre o resultado e a qualidade total é sempre muito complicado.

As dívidas mais comuns envolvem atividades que os desenvolvedores não gostam de fazer e que não são obrigatórias para se obter um resultado (bom ou ruim). São as atividades:

- Documentação
- Escrita de testes
- Resolução de *warnings* e outras pendências indicadas pelo compilador ou ferramentas de análise estática
- *Bugs* difíceis ou chatos que ninguém quer se responsabilizar
- Códigos que precisam de uma nova iteração para solucionar algum problema, notadamente onde existem comentários do tipo "TODO" e "TOFIX" ou alguma técnica para marcar como "Not implemented Yet".

Estas dívidas ocorrem por **desconhecimento do que fazer, desprezo pela atividade ou por falta de condições** de realizar as tarefas, seja por falta de recursos (tempo, dinheiro, pessoas capacitadas, etc.), seja por uma situação legada que dificulta a realização (falta de entendimento e decisões erradas no gerenciamento ou arquitetura).

Há muito tempo sabe-se que gerenciar estas dívidas para elas não saírem do controle é fundamental para evitar problemas maiores e criar uma complexidade acidental. Esta gerência passa por não permitir que as dívidas se acumulem. A soma de dívidas pode causar novas dívidas, exatamente como ocorre em dívidas financeiras.

O que **dívida técnica** provavelmente **não é**: conscientemente deixar funcionalidades para serem implementadas depois se elas não precisam ser implementadas agora e se sabe que não haverá problemas fazer depois. Não podemos considerar como dívidas técnicas qualquer planejamento que deliberadamente indica a criação de novas funcionalidades em momentos posteriores. O que é diferente de atrasos causados por qualquer motivo, inclusive planejamento errado (um exemplo em que a tentativa de melhor organização causa uma dívida técnica).

Também não é a bagunça do projeto.

Obviamente que o que for deixado para depois não pode impedir o andamento normal do projeto. A dívida é aquilo que impede o andamento em boas condições. E é muito fácil achar que algo não está impedindo nada e na verdade não estar. Ele gera juros. A dívida fica maior só porque há dívida e será mais difícil pagar. É muito difícil determinar quando uma dívida pode valor o esforço de tê-la.

Eu vejo uma certa esquizofrenia entre isto e Agile ou metodologias parecidas. Muitos proponentes de Agile pregam não ter dívidas técnicas. Mas como fazer isso com interações tão pequenas? Posso estar enganado, mas tudo o que já vi, a dívida técnica só pode ser combatida em ciclos maiores. No fundo metodologias contrárias ao Agile parecem existir para isso mesmo, garantir que nada fique pra trás. Alguns dirão que o entendimento não é bem este. Mas aí entra o que eu sempre digo, se é complicado demais para entender e fazer certo, provavelmente não é a melhor coisa a seguir. Se Agile fosse tão bom, as pessoas acertariam o jeito de usar mais facilmente. [Isso é corroborado pelo que diz o Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html). Entregar rápido e entregar certo não combinam. Algumas pessoas já aceitam que no fundo é muito raro ver alguém aplicando Agile de verdade, elas aplicam a sua versão do que é Agile.

Pode parecer confuso o que é. Estes termos e metodologias são assim mesmo. Algumas poucas pessoas privilegiadas entendem completamente o seu significado real, o ponto exato de como deve ser aplicado.

Enfim, não devemos temer as dívidas técnicas, devemos saber que elas existem e a melhor forma de gerenciá-las que é a parte mais difícil, ainda bem que não perguntou isto :).

Desconheço medidas que determinam o que seja aceitável, acho pouco provável que exista uma forma relevante de definir isto. É como determinar o progresso de um projeto pela quantidade de linhas de código em um projeto.

> Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight  -- Dizem ter sido dito pelo Bill Gates

A expressão é [creditada ao Ward Cunningham](https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WardExplainsDebtMetaphor).

[image: Carro da Copasa cai em buraco da Copasa]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito legal esse tópico pessoal. Por isso que Scrum trabalha com o conceito de DOD (Definition of Done) está pronto ou não. Entregar rápido não é entregar pela metade. O conceito de Ágil não está ligado somente a velocidade, mas sim ao "valor" do que é entregue. Já trabalhei em times que usavam Scrum corretamente e outros não. Não podemos "culpar" o Agile de dívidas técnicas se é contra o conceito de "ter dívidas técnicas" https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2008/september/definition-of-done-a-reference

Comment: Qualquer metodologia minimamente razoável deveria ser contra dívidas técnicas. Me parece um requisito básico, e não exatamente uma "vantagem" dessa ou daquela.