# O que é Code Smell?

Tags: terminologia

Comecei a estudar `swift` e me deparei com um termo muito utilizado chamado `Code Smell` pelo que consegui entender na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) e em alguns outros sites ele é qualquer sintoma no código fonte que indica um problema mais profundo, e.g: código duplicado.

Por esta definição eu acabo me questionando a seguinte coisa, Code Smell não é a mesma coisa que [os princípios DRY, KISS e YAGNI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23052/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-princ%C3%ADpios-dry-kiss-e-yagni)

Como posso identificar `code smell/bad smell` em um código?

Comment: Já eu achava que era algo relacionado à [dívida técnica](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32420/3117), mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: @Math está lá no artigo da Wikipedia, _"Code smells are an important reason for technical debt."_

Comment: @Piovezan tem razão, eu não cheguei a ler a página, mas sabia que tinha algo a ver :P

Comment: @Math 
Nunca tinha ouvido falar em dívida técnica, acho que são tantos fatores que devem ser considerados na hora de ver se um código pode ser refatorado ou não
que me deixam mais confuso, acabo lembrando de uma frase antiga dos programadores "Se esta funcionando,não mexa."

Comment: Você conhece a expressão "onde há fumaça há fogo"? O sentido disso é, bom, *nem sempre* fumaça quer dizer fogo, mas é um bom indício, então melhor ficar alerta... Da mesa forma, no meu entendimento, *"code smell"* tem o sentido de indicar coisas que não estão "erradas" no código, mas que podem indicar um problema mais profundo. Às vezes o programador se desvia das "boas práticas" por um bom motivo. Mas na maioria das vezes, o faz por ignorância, então é bom ficar atento às possíveis consequências (revisar o código), pois pode não estar quebrado agora mas tem boa chance de quebrar no futuro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Muito bem falado.

Comment: Em bom português, code smell é a famosa "gambiarra".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Determinar o que é ou não um code smell é sempre um julgamento subjetivo, e sempre irá variar de acordo com a linguagem de programação, o desenvolvedor e a metodologia de desenvolvimento.

Existem ferramentas que detectam certos tipos de code smells, como:

Java: Checkstyle, PMD e FindBugs.

.Net: ReSharper.

[Para Php](http://phpmd.org/).

**Alguns Code smells comuns:**

***Código duplicado***: código idêntico ou muito similar existe em mais de um local.

***Método longo***: um método, função ou procedure muito extenso.

***Classe extensa***: uma classe que acabou ficando muito extensa (God Object).

***Feature envy (sem tradução)***: uma classe que utiliza em excesso métodos de outra classe.

***Intimidade inapropriada***: uma classe que possui dependência de detalhes de implementação de outra classe.

***Legado recusado***: uma classe que sobrepõe (override) o método da classe genérica de forma que o contrato da classe genérica não é cumprido pela classe derivada.

***Classe preguiçosa***: classe que faz muito pouco.

***Complexidade artificial***: uso forçado de design patterns extremamente complicados, onde um design simples seria suficiente.

***Identificadores excessivamente longos***: em particular, o uso de convenções de nomes para evitar ambiguidades, o que deveria estar implícito na arquitetura do software.

Answer (score 9):

Não são a mesma coisa. Muitos *code smells* (mau cheiro no código) irão seguir esses princípios de [DRY, KISS e YAGNI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/112052), que são prevalentes em desenvolvimento de software, mas nem todos irão (exemplos: *Excessively short identifiers*, *Constants class*).

Mas independente disso, se as situações de mau cheiro fossem óbvias para todo mundo, não seria preciso compilar uma lista de *code smells* em primeiro lugar. Bastaria dizer "*siga sempre princípios como o DRY, KISS e YAGNI*".

Como foi dito, há ferramentas que detectam alguns *code smells*, mas a forma mais completa de saber se o seu código tem *code smells* é pegar uma boa lista de *code smells* (tem uma por exemplo no livro "Código Limpo" do Robert C. Martin), estudá-los e ver se existem no seu código. Se todos foram óbvios e você evitou todos no seu código, parabéns! Você é muito bom em aplicar os princípios de DRY, KISS e YAGNI, entre outros.

Caso contrário, você conheceu melhor os *code smells* e os princípios por trás deles e com isso saberá ficar mais atento a código com mau cheiro, podendo aplicar isso em seu código existente e em códigos futuros. Isso o ajudará a ter código mais robusto e seguindo bons princípios.

Answer (score 7):

code smell/bad smell, é o termo usado para evidenciar que algo no código não faz sentido(falta de coesão), caso esse problema não seja tratado irá se espalhar, o custo e esforço para corrigi-lo aumentará. Alguns exemplos são classes com mais de uma reponsabilidade e falta de modularização.