# Que passo posso tomar para corrigir o aviso "Raw use of parameterized class 'Class'"?

Tags: java, genéricos

No programa abaixo, tenho a classe `Cow`, a classe `Dragon` derivada da classe `Cow` e a classe `IceDragon` derivada da classe `Dragon`.

Há também a classe `HeiferGenerator`, responsável por criar um array contendo instâncias de `Cow`, `Dragon` e `IceDragon`.

No entanto, na classe `HeifeferGenerator`, recebo o aviso "*Raw use of parameterized class 'Class'*" na linha:

```
private static final Class[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, IceDragon.class};
```

O que posso fazer para corrigir este aviso?

```
// Cow class
public class Cow {

    // Declaring attributes name and image
    private final String name;
    private String image;

    // Constructor to create a new Cow object with parameter name
    public Cow (String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = null;
    }

    // Accessor to return the name of the cow
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Accessor to return the image used to display the cow after the message
    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    // Mutator to set the image used to display the cow after the message
    public void setImage(String _image) {
        this.image = _image;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Dragon class derived from the Cow class
public class Dragon extends Cow {
    // Constructor to create a new Dragon object with parameters name and image
    public Dragon (String name, String image) {
        super(name);
        setImage(image);
    }

    // Function to return true for the default Dragon type
    public boolean canBreatheFire() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
// IceDragon class derived from the Dragon class
public class IceDragon extends Dragon {
    // Constructor to create a new IceDragon object with parameters name and image
    public IceDragon (String name, String image) {
        super(name, image);
    }

    // Function to return false for the IceDragon type
    public boolean canBreatheFire() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class HeiferGenerator
{
    public static Cow[] getCows()
    {
        if (cows == null)
        {
            cows = new Cow[cowNames.length + dragonNames.length];

            // Add the "regular" cows
            for (int index = 0; index < cowNames.length; index++)
            {
                cows[index] = new Cow(cowNames[index]);
                cows[index].setImage(quoteLines + cowImages[index]);
            }

            // Add the dragons
            for (int offset = cowNames.length, index = 0; index < dragonNames.length; index++)
            {
                try
                {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Constructor<Dragon> constructor = dragonTypes[index].getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
                    cows[offset + index] = constructor.newInstance(dragonNames[index], quoteLines + dragonImage);
                }
                catch (Exception ignored) { }
            }
        }

        return cows;
    }

    // Hard-coded values for some of the cows
    private static final String[] cowNames = { "heifer", "kitteh" };

    private static final String quoteLines =        "       \\\n" +
            "        \\\n" +
            "         \\\n";

    private static final String[] cowImages = { "        ^__^\n" +
            "        (oo)\\_______\n" +
            "        (__)\\       )\\/\\\n" +
            "            ||----w |\n" +
            "            ||     ||\n",


            "       (\"`-'  '-/\") .___..--' ' \"`-._\n" +
                    "         ` *_ *  )    `-.   (      ) .`-.__. `)\n" +
                    "         (_Y_.) ' ._   )   `._` ;  `` -. .-'\n" +
                    "      _.. `--'_..-_/   /--' _ .' ,4\n" +
                    "   ( i l ),-''  ( l i),'  ( ( ! .-'\n"
    };

    private static final  String[] dragonNames = { "dragon", "ice-dragon" };
    private static final Class[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, Dragon.class};


    private static final String dragonImage =     "           |\\___/|       /\\  //|\\\\\n" +
            "           /0  0  \\__   /  \\// | \\ \\\n" +
            "          /     /  \\/_ /   //  |  \\  \\\n" +
            "          \\_^_\\'/   \\/_   //   |   \\   \\\n" +
            "          //_^_/     \\/_ //    |    \\    \\\n" +
            "       ( //) |        \\ //     |     \\     \\\n" +
            "     ( / /) _|_ /   )   //     |      \\     _\\\n" +
            "   ( // /) '/,_ _ _/  ( ; -.   |    _ _\\.-~       .-~~~^-.\n" +
            " (( / / )) ,-{        _      `.|.-~-.          .~         `.\n" +
            "(( // / ))  '/\\      /                ~-. _.-~      .-~^-.  \\\n" +
            "(( /// ))      `.   {            }                 /      \\  \\\n" +
            " (( / ))     .----~-.\\        \\-'               .~         \\  `.   __\n" +
            "            ///.----..>        \\            _ -~            `.  ^-`  \\\n" +
            "              ///-._ _ _ _ _ _ _}^ - - - - ~                   `-----'\n";

      private static Cow[] cows = null;

  }
```

<sub>Tradução de [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891186) e [espanhol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/551912)</sub>

Comment: O erro ocorre porque a classe `java.lang.Class<T>` é uma classe genérica onde o parâmetro `T` é o tipo da classe a ser modelada ao instanciar. Seria interessante saber o objetivo da linha `private static final Class[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, IceDragon.class};` como não sei o que é ou não o melhor para que pretende o máximo que posso indicar fazer é `private static final Class<?>[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, IceDragon.class};`

Comment: Analisando a classe `HeiferGenerator` parece que pretende utilizar reflexão para instanciar múltiplas classes. Geralmente recorrer a reflexão não é melhor alternativa, como sugestão pesquise sobe [Factory Patterns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/137387) e [Design Patterns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/137387)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Resposta curta

Bastaria fazer:

```
private static final Class<?>[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, IceDragon.class};
```

E depois, no trecho em que o array é usado:

```java
Constructor<?> constructor = dragonTypes[index].getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
cows[offset + index] = (Cow) constructor.newInstance(dragonNames[index], quoteLines + dragonImage);
```

Mas talvez não seja a melhor solução (mais detalhes abaixo).

---

## Resposta longa

A classe `java.lang.Class` é um [tipo genérico](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), ou seja, ela está atrelada à um outro tipo que pode ser parametrizado. Veja na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) que ela é definida como `Class<T>`: este `T` é o "tipo parametrizado".

Para mais detalhes, veja: [O que é programação genérica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/112052)

De forma **bem** resumida, quando você está usando um tipo genérico sem especificar o tipo que corresponde ao `T`, ele é chamado de [*raw type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Ex:

```java
// tipo especificado é Integer
Class<Integer> integerClass = Integer.class;
// tipo especificado é String
Class<String> stringClass = String.class;

// sem tipo especificado, é um raw type
Class c = String.class;
```

E quando você está usando um *raw type*, o compilador costuma dar esses avisos que você viu.

---

No caso específico de arrays, não é possível criar arrays de tipos parametrizados (ver mais [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9542131)).

Então para eliminar o *warning*, não daria para usar um tipo específico, por isso se usa o *wildcard* `<?>`, que indica um "tipo desconhecido". Inclusive o [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) diz o seguinte sobre o `<?>`:

> *When the code is using methods in the generic class that don't depend on the type parameter (...) In fact, `Class<?>` is so often used because most of the methods in `Class<T>` do not depend on `T`*.

Ou seja, em vez de `Class`, usamos `Class<?>`:

```
private static final Class<?>[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, IceDragon.class};
```

Claro que aí teria que mudar também a parte em que o array é usado:

```java
Constructor<?> constructor = dragonTypes[index].getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
cows[offset + index] = (Cow) constructor.newInstance(dragonNames[index], quoteLines + dragonImage);
```

Pois como os elementos do array são `Class<?>`, então o resultado de `getConstructor` será um `Constructor<?>`, e portanto o método `newInstance` não sabe que retornará um `Dragon`. Mas como o array `cows` é de `Cow`, então faz-se necessário o *cast* para este tipo.

---

Uma opção menos pior seria trocar para um `java.util.List`, assim é possível parametrizar o tipo, inclusive podendo restringi-lo:

```java
// não esqueça de importar:
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HeiferGenerator {
    private static final List<Class<? extends Dragon>> dragonTypes = Arrays.asList(Dragon.class, IceDragon.class);

    etc...
}
```

O *wildcard* `<? extends Dragon>` limita o tipo de elementos que podem estar na lista (no caso, somente `Dragon` ou suas subclasses). Assim fica mais restrito do que `<?>` (que basicamente aceita "qualquer coisa"), além de não dar mais o *warning* de *raw types*. Quanto ao uso, também mudaria:

```java
Constructor<? extends Dragon> constructor = dragonTypes.get(index).getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
cows[offset + index] = constructor.newInstance(dragonNames[index], quoteLines + dragonImage);
```

Ou seja, o `Constructor` também fica restrito aos mesmos tipos (no caso, `Dragon` e suas subclasses), e por isso não é mais necessário o *cast* na segunda linha, já que `Dragon` e suas subclasses são compatíveis com `Cow`.

---

### Será que precisa de *reflection*?

Dito isso, *reflection* não costuma ser a melhor solução para estes casos. Claro que cada caso é um caso, mas geralmente ela é um [*code smell*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100016/112052) (sinal de que algo "não cheira bem" e que provavelmente há uma maneira melhor de resolver). Claro que há exceções, mas não me parece ser o seu caso.

> <sup>*Não vou nem entrar no mérito de um `Dragon` herdar de `Cow` (um dragão é um sub-tipo de vaca?), mas enfim...*</sup>

Por exemplo, você está contando que os construtores de `Dragon` (e subclasses) tenham sempre dois argumentos do tipo `String`. Se um dia uma subclasse tiver um construtor diferente (ou mesmo se precisar mudar o construtor de uma já existente), terá que mudar a lógica (dependendo do tipo de dragão, muda o tipo e/ou quantidade dos argumentos do construtor, etc).

E já que existe a possibilidade de fazer algo diferente dependendo do tipo, uma alternativa melhor seria não usar *reflection*, e simplesmente parametrizar a criação das criaturas de alguma maneira mais genérica. Uma sugestão (*sem saber todos os requisitos, portanto um grande tiro no escuro*) seria:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class HeiferGenerator {
    private static enum CreatureType {
        COW, DRAGON, ICE_DRAGON;
    }
    private static class CreatureData {
        // classe privada (só vai ser usada dentro de HeiferGenerator), então os campos
        // não precisam ser private e nem ter getters/setters
        CreatureType type;
        String name, image;
        public CreatureData(CreatureType type, String name, String image) {
            this.type = type;
            this.name = name;
            this.image = image;
        }
    }

    private static final String QUOTE_LINES = "       \\\n        \\\n         \\\n";
    private static final String DRAGON_IMAGE = "           |\\___/|       /\\  //|\\\\\n"
            + "           /0  0  \\__   /  \\// | \\ \\\n"
            + "          /     /  \\/_ /   //  |  \\  \\\n"
            + "          \\_^_\\'/   \\/_   //   |   \\   \\\n"
            + "          //_^_/     \\/_ //    |    \\    \\\n"
            + "       ( //) |        \\ //     |     \\     \\\n"
            + "     ( / /) _|_ /   )   //     |      \\     _\\\n"
            + "   ( // /) '/,_ _ _/  ( ; -.   |    _ _\\.-~       .-~~~^-.\n"
            + " (( / / )) ,-{        _      `.|.-~-.          .~         `.\n"
            + "(( // / ))  '/\\      /                ~-. _.-~      .-~^-.  \\\n"
            + "(( /// ))      `.   {            }                 /      \\  \\\n"
            + " (( / ))     .----~-.\\        \\-'               .~         \\  `.   __\n"
            + "            ///.----..>        \\            _ -~            `.  ^-`  \\\n"
            + "              ///-._ _ _ _ _ _ _}^ - - - - ~                   `-----'\n";

    private static Cow[] COWS = null;
    // lista contendo o tipo, nome e imagem de cada criatura
    private static final List<CreatureData> CREATURES_DEFINITIONS = Arrays.asList(
            new CreatureData(CreatureType.COW, "heifer",
                    "        ^__^\n"
                    + "        (oo)\\_______\n"
                    + "        (__)\\       )\\/\\\n"
                    + "            ||----w |\n"
                    + "            ||     ||\n"),
            new CreatureData(CreatureType.COW, "kitteh",
                    "       (\"`-'  '-/\") .___..--' ' \"`-._\n"
                    + "         ` *_ *  )    `-.   (      ) .`-.__. `)\n"
                    + "         (_Y_.) ' ._   )   `._` ;  `` -. .-'\n"
                    + "      _.. `--'_..-_/   /--' _ .' ,4\n"
                    + "   ( i l ),-''  ( l i),'  ( ( ! .-'\n"),
            new CreatureData(CreatureType.DRAGON, "dragon", DRAGON_IMAGE),
            new CreatureData(CreatureType.ICE_DRAGON, "ice-dragon", DRAGON_IMAGE)
    );

    public static Cow[] getCOWS() {
        if (COWS == null) {
            COWS = new Cow[CREATURES_DEFINITIONS.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < COWS.length; i++) {
                CreatureData cd = CREATURES_DEFINITIONS.get(i);
                switch (cd.type) {
                    case COW:
                        COWS[i] = new Cow(cd.name);
                        COWS[i].setImage(QUOTE_LINES + cd.image);
                        break;
                    case DRAGON:
                        COWS[i] = new Dragon(cd.name, QUOTE_LINES + cd.image);
                        break;
                    case ICE_DRAGON:
                        COWS[i] = new IceDragon(cd.name, QUOTE_LINES + cd.image);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return COWS;
    }
}
```

Talvez o `enum` e a *inner class* `CreatureData` sejam excesso de preciosismo (poderia simplesmente ser um `int` indicando o tipo, por exemplo, e um array de strings contendo o nome e imagem), mas foi só para ilustrar a ideia de que não precisa de *reflection* (assim elimina a preocupação de lidar com o aviso de *raw type*, além de - na minha opinião - deixar o código mais legível e extensível).

Note que também mudei os nomes para ficar de acordo com as [convenções de nomenclatura da linguagem](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

---

#### Outra sugestão

E claro que daria para sugerir muitas variações, como por exemplo não usar o `enum CreatureType` e alterar a classe `CreatureData` para:

```
private static class CreatureData {
    Class<? extends Cow> type;
    String name, image;
    public CreatureData(Class<? extends Cow> type, String name, String image) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Assim, as definições das criaturas e sua criação ficariam:

```
private static final List<CreatureData> CREATURES_DEFINITIONS = Arrays.asList(
        new CreatureData(Cow.class, "heifer",
                "        ^__^\n"
                + "        (oo)\\_______\n"
                + "        (__)\\       )\\/\\\n"
                + "            ||----w |\n"
                + "            ||     ||\n"),
        new CreatureData(Cow.class, "kitteh",
                "       (\"`-'  '-/\") .___..--' ' \"`-._\n"
                + "         ` *_ *  )    `-.   (      ) .`-.__. `)\n"
                + "         (_Y_.) ' ._   )   `._` ;  `` -. .-'\n"
                + "      _.. `--'_..-_/   /--' _ .' ,4\n"
                + "   ( i l ),-''  ( l i),'  ( ( ! .-'\n"),
        new CreatureData(Dragon.class, "dragon", DRAGON_IMAGE),
        new CreatureData(IceDragon.class, "ice-dragon", DRAGON_IMAGE)
);

public static Cow[] getCOWS() {
    if (COWS == null) {
        COWS = new Cow[CREATURES_DEFINITIONS.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < COWS.length; i++) {
            CreatureData cd = CREATURES_DEFINITIONS.get(i);
            if (cd.type.equals(Cow.class)) {
                COWS[i] = new Cow(cd.name);
                COWS[i].setImage(QUOTE_LINES + cd.image);
            } else if (cd.type.equals(Dragon.class)) {
                COWS[i] = new Dragon(cd.name, QUOTE_LINES + cd.image);
            } else if (cd.type.equals(IceDragon.class)) {
                COWS[i] = new IceDragon(cd.name, QUOTE_LINES + cd.image);
            }
        }
    }
    return COWS;
}
```

E mil outras variações são possíveis (todas sem precisar de *reflection*).

Answer (score -3):

O aviso "*Raw use of parameterized class 'Class'*" indica que uma classe genérica está sendo usada sem especificar um tipo. Para corrigir isso, você deve especificar um tipo para a classe genérica.

Para corrigir esse aviso, você pode

- converter a classe para uma classe não genérica ou
- especificar os tipos de parâmetros para a classe.

A primeira solução pode ser demonstrada como segue:

```java
public class Classe {
  private final Object valor;

  public Classe(Object valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
  }

  public Object getValor() {
    return valor;
  }
}
```