# O que é um anti-pattern?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Já sabemos [O que é Design Pattern?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101). Mas o que é um anti-pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele é o oposto do *design pattern*. Da mesma forma que eu não gosto de ver estes como sendo sinônimo de boas práticas, não gosto de ver os *anti-patterns* como sinônimos de más práticas. Ainda que eventualmente eles se confundam.

Ele é uma resposta que costuma ser dada para um problema recorrente que é considerada como ruim e não deveria ser aplicada.

Pela [definição da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern):

> O antipadrão é um processo, estrutura ou padrão de ação comumente
> usado que, apesar de inicialmente parecer uma resposta adequada e
> eficaz a um problema, tem mais consequências ruins do que boas.
>
> Existe outra solução para o problema que o antipadrão está tentando
> solucionar. Esta solução é documentada, repetível e comprovadamente
> eficaz onde o antipadrão não é.

Em desenvolvimento de software ele é algo um pouco mais elaborado e com um escopo maior do que o [*code smell*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100016/101).

Ao contrário do termo original que está em todo lugar, conforme minha resposta lá, e que eles são tão bons que são oficializados em *features*, os *anti-patterns* apenas devem ser evitados porque sabe-se ser ruins.

Isso não quer dizer que eles nunca devam ser usados, até porque se virar regra de ouro (no sentido ruim da expressão) já perde o sentido de uso. Sempre que tiver um motivo para usar algo considerado ruim, desde que saiba o que está fazendo e seja necessário, que o benefício seja maior que o malefício, então é ok usar. Deve-se evitar sim, mas não proibir o uso.

Justamente pela controvérsia o mesmo padrão pode ser considerado DP ou AP, dependendo de quem diz ou do contexto.

Da mesma forma que algumas pessoas desenvolvem softwares baseados em DPs (ela tem a solução dada pelo DP e procura um problema para encaixar) e isto é um dos maiores *anti-patterns* existentes, os APs podem ser abusados fazendo a pessoa fugir deles e criando outros APs para atender a fórmula mágica.

Eles deveriam ser mais famosos que os exemplos positivos. Alguns são, mas não são vistos da mesma maneira que os DPs. O problema é que os DPs ficaram famosos em demasia.

Da mesma forma que existe um livro que tornou famosos alguns *design patterns*, e fizeram as pessoas acreditarem que só é DP se está no [livro da GoF](https://wiki.c2.com/?GangOfFour), um [livro de *anti-patterns*](http://antipatterns.com/) foi escrito. Os *anti-patterns* não ganharam tanta notoriedade e a mesma conotação de DP. Os DPs do livro se tornaram instrumento de marketing mais do que de engenharia.

Um dos melhores catálogos de *anti-patterns* é a [C2 wiki](https://wiki.c2.com/?AntiPatternsCatalog). Ela foi criada para isso. A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anti-patterns) pode ser uma boa referência inicial. Aqui temos várias perguntas sobre eles, por exemplo [O que são Objetos Deus?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415961/101).

Lembre-se que a lista nunca está completa. Você pode criar um *anti-pattern*.

Eles também nunca foram tão oficializados como alguns *design patterns*. Até porque se é para não seguir não precisa de tanto formalismo. Mas deveria ser sempre bem elaborado para a pessoa tomar boas decisões e não apenas ter como uma receita de bolo universal e incontestável.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu achava que XGH era um anti-pattern, até eu ver tanto código usando essa "metodologia ágil", que virou um pattern bem recorrente na minha carreira.

Comment: Bom, eu discordo, um anti-pattern é um padrão de projeto comum que é considerado ineficaz ou prejudicial. Ele é o oposto de um padrão de projeto, que é uma abordagem comprovada e bem-sucedida para resolver um problema de projeto específico. Os anti-padrões são frequentemente reconhecidos por desenvolvedores experientes que os testemunharam causando problemas em projetos anteriores. Eles podem ser causados por um mau entendimento ou aplicação de um padrão de projeto, ou podem ser soluções fáceis que causam problemas de escalabilidade ou manutenção no futuro. É a tal da "gambiarra".

Comment: Onde está a discordância? Além do fato de não ser uma gambiarra que tem uma definição completamente diferente.