# Qual a diferença entre parâmetros e atributos na criação de tabelas em um sistema?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, estrutura-de-dados

Sou migrador de dados e todos os dias, tenho o prazer e desprazer de conhecer inúmeros bancos de dados dos mais variados sistemas comerciais existentes no mercado. Minha dúvida está na forma com que as pessoas modelam os campos das tabelas. Eu ilustrei duas tabelas:

[image: Modelo com colunas de parâmetros]

Por que as pessoas criam tabelas de parâmetros gerais onde criam campos em forma de parâmetro e guardam tais informações?

Um exemplo seriam os campos `PermitirVendasSemEstoque` (Produtos) e `PermitirAnaliseCredito` (Clientes). Eles são atributos de suas respectivas tabelas, mas já encontrei casos onde eles estavam em forma de parâmetros armazenados em outra tabela chamada de configurações ou parâmetros e eram chamados quando as telas eram chamadas. Se eles são atributos de uma tabela, por que raios, são tratados como parâmetros?

Vi muitos casos semelhantes com tabelas de configurações do sistema, onde é necessário armazenar informações como cores de telas, versões do sistema, preferências do usuário, dentre outros. Isso me fez ter dúvidas sobre a diferença entre um atributo e parâmetro.

Existem boas práticas a serem seguidas para a modelagem das tabelas em relação ao que foi citado na dúvida anterior? Seria melhor jogar todos os campos em uma tabela ou fazer uma tabela global de parâmetros e jogar tudo dentro? Como identificar o que deverá ir para cada tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vixi, está misturando 3 coisas aí e realmente tudo fica confuso. Em banco de dados, e até em UML, atributo é o termo usado, em linguagens de programação como o C# não, [o termo correto é campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), ou como é usado em *models* do Entity Framework ou MVC, propriedade (que é um conceito um pouco diferente).

> Sou migrador de dados e todos os dias, tenho o prazer e desprazer de conhecer inúmeros bancos de dados dos mais variados sistemas comerciais existentes no mercado. Minha dúvida está na forma com que as pessoas modelam os campos das tabelas

Sistemas comerciais do tipo ERP de prateleira costumam ser usados por variados tipos de empresa, cada uma com suas necessidades, então o desenvolvimento desses softwares é bem diferente do que se ensina por aí. Eu sou especialista neste tipo de software. Cada empresa opera de uma maneira diferente e não tem outra forma a não ser permitir parametrização do que fazer. Tem como fazer isso melhor ou pior, e minha experiência é que todos erram feio porque:

- não entendem bem o conceito de flexibilização
- não entendem bem o domínio que estão trabalhando
- as pessoas tendem a simplificar o problema por não enxergarem o mundo real como ele realmente é
- são péssimos em prever o futuro (todos humanos)
- geralmente precisam dar uma solução rápida e [não tem tempo para resolver do jeito certo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32420/101)
- [não possuem conhecimento, habilidade e atitude correta perante ao seu trabalho](https://www.eximiaco.tech/pt/2019/05/31/somos-amadores-remunerados/) e isto inclui não se importar com o certo
- não é fácil acertar isso.

Há quem exagere, há quem modele uma coisa como se fosse outra, há quem escolhe o mecanismo errado para dar essa flexibilidade.

> Por que as pessoas criam tabelas de Parâmetros gerais onde criam campos em forma de parâmetro e guardam tais informações?

Há casos que nem é flexibilidade do software, é flexibilidade do item ou mesmo uma condição que sequer pode ser considerada um parâmetro. Não me parece que `PermitirVendasSemEstoque` ou `UtilizaBalanca` seja um parâmetro. `PermitirAnaliseCredito` ou `PermitirEdicaoDescricao` pode ser, mas depende de mais contexto para ter certeza. Onde está faz muita diferença, por estar na tabela e ser pertencente a cada item cadastrado não parece parâmetro de software.

Por exemplo, `UtilizaBalanca` é algo importante porque tem item que tem um peso controlado pela balança e isso tem implicações no sistema, mas tem produto que não se comporta assim, então você tem que lidar com isso, que outra forma saberia se deve controlar esse item de uma forma ou de outra se não tiver uma informação que indique isso?

> Existem boas práticas a serem seguidas para a modelagem das tabelas em relação ao que foi citado na dúvida 1?

Não, sempre digo que não deve se apegar às "boas práticas". A pergunta é genérica demais para sequer poder citar alguns itens a serem observados, e mesmo que cite ele não pode ser aplicado a todos os casos.

> Seria melhor jogar todos os campos em uma tabela ou fazer uma tabela global de parâmetros e jogar tudo dentro?

Depende do que quer fazer, não tem melhor, não é uma escolha geral, não existe uma situação única, deve ser o mais granular quanto for necessário. Se é algo que deve influenciar no todo deve ser global, se é algo que deve funcionar em certo contexto deve parametrizar para este contexto, se é algo para uma tabela, para um grupo de itens ou um item específico deve ser em cada um destes. Isso é modelar. Ao contrário do que as pessoas acreditam modelar não é pegar uma regra e aplicar, é entender o problema e criar um modelo que resolve bem tudo o que precisa hoje e que seja fácil evoluir no futuro.

Modelar é o aspecto mais importante do desenvolvimento de software, na verdade o único que a pessoa tem que ser muito boa. E todos falham nisso, apenas existem os que falham menos.

> Como identificar o que deverá ir para cada tabela?

Absurdamente amplo responder isso a não ser dizer para verificar a necessidade, que é uma resposta muito genérica para servir para alguma coisa. Ou posso responder o que já disse antes, coloque em tabela geral o que é geral, em tabela específica o que é específico. Não tem mágica, tem que saber o que é geral ou específico em cada caso.

Para fazer isso é necessário:

- bom entendimento de lógica geral (não de programação)
- de interpretação de texto (e criação do texto)
- entendimento matemático (não é decorar fórmula)
- uma capacidade de aprendizado bem ampla para poder aprofundar o conhecimento sobre um domínio que ainda não conhece bem e ver o que nem sempre é óbvio
- e experiência para evitar armadilhas, algo que só pode acontecer quando já caiu em muitas.

Criar CRUDs simples é fácil, fazer softwares é bem difícil porque não basta conhecer uma linguagem de programação e o básico de um banco de dados.

Só para tentar dar um exemplo, considere que `PermitirAnaliseCredito` seja algo que uma empresa (que usa o software) faz ou não faz, de forma geral, para todos os clientes. Onde vai colocar isso? Deveria ser óbvio que é algo global. Se essa decisão depende de cada cliente individual seria óbvio que deve ser um campo da tabela de cliente, certo?

Eu costumo dizer que as pessoas erram até quando criam uma tabela `Clientes` ([não existe essa entidade no mundo real, existe uma relação de clientela que é conceitualmente muito diferente e faz toda diferença na hora de modelar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)). Respondi sobre [DRY de informação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402541/101), se você tem uma mesma entidade cadastrada duas vezes, como cliente e como fornecedor por exemplo, não tem uma informação canônica, então muita coisa vai sair errada daí pra frente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse exemplo de um parâmetro `PermitirVendasSemEstoque`... 
Você diz em relação ao "cadastro do item", porque no caso você poderia "movimentar" estoque ou não por um "tipo de operação", ou de forma alguma?

Comment: Então, não posso afirmar nada sem entender o problema, mas é uma possibilidade ser isso, pode ser outra coisa.

Comment: E ainda assim, se você precisa "obrigar" uma "pesagem", não tendo um parâmetro `UtilizaBalanca`, seria então uma tabela separada para "relacionar" os itens obrigatórios?

Comment: Talvez, sem detalhes não tenho como responder. É o que eu falo as pessoas acham que dá para tomar decisões sem detalhes. Note que eu peço detalhes em muitas perguntas e não vem, o problema das pessoas é que elas não sabem fazer perguntas, elas não conseguem dar os detalhes necessários para a pergunta ser compreensível e poder ser respondida adequadamente, aí a pessoa fica brava, inclusive porque algumas pessoas acham que podem responder sem detalhes, ela é ingênua nesse ponto. Modelagem é fazer as perguntas do jeito certo , a resposta é só consequência da pergunta certa.

Comment: Por isso falo em interpretação de texto quando vai modelar.