# Uma classe cliente que cadastra clientes nela mesma seria uma classe coesa?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software

Estudando coesão. Visto que uma classe coesa é aquela que possui responsabilidade única, faria sentido a classe `Cliente` possuir esses métodos? Se pensarmos no mundo real, um cliente não pode cadastrar um cliente, isso seria responsabilidade do funcionário ou sistema. Dessa forma, a classe `Cliente` não deveria apenas armazenar os dados do cliente?

```
public class Cliente {
    public String name;
    public String phone;
    public String email;

    public Cliente(String name, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void addCliente(Cliente c){
        //implementação
    }
    public void removeCliente(Cliente c){
        //implementação
    }

}
```

Comment: Está correto o seu racional. Um cliente não adiciona outro cliente, essa ideia não se traduz no mundo real. Esses conceitos de CRUD (criar, atualizar, deletar), são tratados em outra classe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta simples é não. Porém a lógica apresentada para não fazer isso não é bem essa.

A resposta mais aprofundada é: depende. Sempre.

O erro mais comum que as pessoas cometem é querer definir algo universalmente. Eu sempre falo que se as respostas já existissem de forma fixa não precisaria mais um monte de gente fazendo sistemas. O trabalho ainda existe porque cada situação é diferente e sem pegar todos os requisitos não dá para responder isso.

Tudo pode se o requisito for colhido corretamente, fizer sentido e for viável.

Dentro da normalidade um `Cliente` só tem dados sobre um cliente, nada além disso. Qualquer coisa além disso é responsabilidade demais para ele.

Isso não quer dizer que é proibido violar isso e dar a essa classe mais responsabilidades, tudo pode se você souber o que está fazendo. Se não souber não é uma regra que salvará a pessoa.

Eu nem sei bem o que é cadastrar no contexto da pergunta. É digitar dados? É armazenar no banco de dados? Sem entender completamente o problema e com precisão não tem como tomar decisões corretas. O código não mostra onde vai cadastrar.

Se for para digitar dados então o normal é ter outra classe responsável por isso.

Certamente não seria uma de funcionário. Nem vou falar porque pode ser que a digitação possa ocorrer por alguém que não seja funcionário (tem requisito assim), pode ser feito pelo próprio cliente fisicamente (muito comum ao contrário do que a pergunta acha), o que não quer dizer que a classe deva fazer isso.

Digitação é UI, nada tem a ver com a entidade do cliente em si. Você pode ter, talvez, um CRUD para o cliente, mas isso não é no `Cliente`. Um dos maiores erros é fazer a interação com usuário acontecer junto com a entidade. No passado se fazia muito isso. Imagina um dia mudar a forma de UI. Loucura completa.

Mas não é funcionário porque então essa classe teria que ter quase tudo o que o sistema permite fazer, porque boa parte das coisas do sistema um funcionário faz.

Pior ainda, a mesma coisa pode ser feita por mais pessoas, não só o funcionário. É uma bagunça completa tentar pensar nisso.

Nem entrei no mérito que até [o cliente já deve ser um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101), igual ao funcionário. [Circunstancialmente alguém é cliente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101), é uma relação e não uma entidade real. Uma mesma entidade pode ser cliente e [funcionário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313990/101), entre outras coisas, ao mesmo tempo. Tenho [diversas respostas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101) que mostra que quase todos sistemas estão errados quando adotam essa estratégia de interpretar a relação, o [papel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101), como se fosse uma entidade do mundo real. Incluindo os maiores ERPs do mercado. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101), entre outras.

Se é para armazenar em um banco de dados cai no mesmo problema da UI. Até porque a forma de armazenar pode trocar ele não pode estar na entidade) ou no papel que é o mais correto). Não faz sentido misturar essas coisas.

E pensa em outra coisa. Se você tiver uma classe `Jogador` e você usará ela para formar um `Time`. Quem deve ser responsável por colocar um jogador no time, o jogador ou o time? Apenas entre essas opções. Me parece óbvio que é a entidade que agrupa jogadores que deve fazer isso, novamente, entre essas duas opções.

Aí você pode pensar: não é o técnico que põe um jogador no time? E aí cai em algo semelhante ao funcionário? Até poderia, mas eu duvido que seja. Sistemas são mais complexos que isso, se você não fizer o certo a manutenção será complicada no futuro. Não é o técnico que põe alguém no time, é uma comissão de pessoas. O técnico pode fazer algo para depois o jogador entrar no time, mas não é ele que coloca. Tem que pensar como é o processo real. Artificialmente pensando o time poderia ter uma ação de adição de um jogador dentro dele, entre outras opções que pode-se fazer com o time. E talvez só algumas classes poderiam chamar esse método.

E nem estou falando que teria algo de UI ou DB nesse time, é só a entidade na aplicação, se precisar interagir ou persistir em algum lugar serão outras classes que farão isso, ligadas de alguma forma com a `Time`.

Então o meu entendimento é que você precisa de uma entidade que "coleciona" clientes, e aí claro, ela tem capacidade de adicioná-los ou removê-los. Ou melhor ainda, seria uma coleção de pessoas que possuem diversas relações com a organização dona da aplicação, talvez separadas em físicas, jurídicas e quem sabe outras, como estrangeiras.

É, é complicado fazer certo, mais ainda sem requisitos concretos. Por isso a maioria faz errado para "ganhar tempo". E depois corre atrás o prejuízo, gastando mais tempo, fazendo gambiarras, remodelando tudo, [pagando os juros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32420/101).

Eu não posso garantir, mas provavelmente aprendeu OOP como a maioria das pessoas aprendem, ou seja, com exemplos artificiais. Esses exemplos, de livro mesmo, alguns consagrados, ensinam o mecanismo, mas não ensinam modelar sistemas. Pelo contrário faz todo mundo entender tudo errado como se programa orientado a objeto de verdade. Mas não está em um caminho tão errado, a base da pergunta estava indo melhor do que muitos entendem.

Na dúvida a [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) se dá colocando menos nas classes, mas claro se colocar muito menos a coesão é perdida também, e isso é só experiência, não tem receita pronta.

Eu adoro ver as pessoas tentando aprender o certo, mas cada vez eu vejo que a pressão por "resultados" faz as pessoas entregarem "o primeiro modelo que vem à cabeça", muitas vezes seguem alguma receita de bolo, e torce para ser o certo para ela.

Comment: No caso o Cliente seria adicionado a uma lista de Clientes, mas para mim não fez sentido essa lista estar dentro da própria Classe do Cliente e a ela conter métodos de remoção e adição. Muito obrigado, sua resposta clareou mais minha mente :D