Como desenvolver sites de uma maneira eficiente
Olá, pessoal!
Estudo programação em Python desde 2020 e, em 2021, comecei a trabalhar com desenvolvimento web, com back-end em Python (provavelmente não foi a melhor escolha, mas seguimos).
Atualmente, estou enfrentando um problema: desde que descobri o JavaScript, passei a desenvolver sites utilizando apenas HTML, CSS e JS puros, sem frameworks ou bibliotecas para facilitar o processo. Gosto de projetos simples e, por isso, acabei desenvolvendo uma boa base nessas tecnologias.
O problema é que estou trabalhando em parceria com uma agência de marketing e percebi que, para os padrões dela, a velocidade com que consigo criar um site institucional é muito baixa. Isso se deve, em parte, ao fato de que trabalhar apenas com o básico exige fazer tudo manualmente, o que, com o tempo, se torna cansativo e até confuso.
Gostaria de dicas dos desenvolvedores mais experientes: como vocês tornam o workflow mais eficiente?
Um ponto importante: há alguns meses, experimentei ferramentas como Bootstrap, Tailwind, Vue e React. Porém, não me adaptei muito bem, especialmente aos frameworks. Talvez seja falta de costume, mas não tenho certeza. Qualquer sugestão será muito bem-vinda. Agradeço desde já!

Tudo depende conhecimento e pratica, e o uso de frameworks e uikits para html+css é questão de opinião... Eu não uso frameworks/uikits e mesmo assim crio páginas rapidamente, que também são responsivas+adaptativas. A única parte que sempre toma tempo geralmente é a parte das imagens, principalmente quando você recebe em formatos, tamanhos ou cortes inconvenientes para web. Usar uikits/frameworks podem até ajudar, mas também dependerá de bastante conhecimento e pratica.

Incrível é uma agência não ter um CMS próprio pronto pra não ter que usar essas coisas. Em 1998 eu trabalhei em agência que já inha isso (o tempo gasto era em fazer o marketing de fato, e produzir as artes - isso feito, o site a gente podia por no ar em menos de 1 hora), Note, estou falando de algo de quase 30 anos atrás.

@Largato, Concordo com você, de fato no passado, a estrutura de um CMS próprio permitia um fluxo muito mais eficiente. No entanto, hoje em dia, ainda enfrentamos situações em que a adaptação a novas tecnologias e a complexidade dos projetos acabam sobrecarregando o processo. Talvez seja falta de investimento ou simplesmente a adaptação mais lenta às mudanças tecnológicas. O fato é: cedo ou tarde se adaptar...

Na verdade hoje as coisas sao absurdamente mais fáceis. E mais simples. Complexidade de projeto na maioria das vezes surge por ter praticamente só gente mal formada atualmente. Falo sem maldade, mas em décadas de mercado, hoje tenho dificuldade de achar gente capacitada - não só na parte técnica, mas na maturidade profissional, justamente por encontrar só "amontoadores de coisa pronta", sem domínio de fato da tecnologia. Tem que tomar cuidado de não ir por esse caminho (modinhas e frameworks porcos, etc) e dominar bem as coisas, para fazer parte da meia dúzia que realmente produz coisa séria.

E sobre o CMS ainda é válido o comentário, infelizmente também o que mais vejo hoje são equipes gigantes consumindo recursos, banda e servidor pra no fim fazer algo que fica inferior a um template do Wix. Chega a ser ilógico. PS: tou de certa forma tentando dar as dicas que os youtubers com gel no cabelo não vão falar. Pegar pesado na crítica não dá view e nem like, mas é pra fazer um contraponto com o que a maioria vai te dizer.

@leensc e demais, isso tem nome: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32420/101
